# Bibs & Bobs vs. Bits & Bobs

Tags: expressions, dialects

When I was a relative newcomer to Yorkshire, in the North of England, I was slightly annoyed when I heard people talking about 'bibs and bobs' (meaning odds and ends). I wanted to correct them by saying it should be 'bits and bobs' but I realised that this had become a dialect issue. I'm wondering if 'bibs and bobs' is in common use in other parts of the UK. (By the way, I know I'm an established Yorkshireman now because I've recently named my new cat Bibs and Bobs.)

Comment: I'm in Derbyshire, my mother was from East Yorkshire, and I've never heard it.

Comment: (I'd never heard the ***bibs*** version before, but apparently it was asked about here a decade ago. So far as I'm concerned, ***bobs*** is just a more alliterative alternative to ***bits and pieces***, where by *further* alliteration (or mishearing) some people have shifted the first term to ***bibs***.)